# Reading Multiple Spreadsheets - File Paths From Central Spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am attempting to load multiple (hundreds) of spreadsheets into one dataframe. The problem is these spreadsheets are located in different folders/paths. I am hoping to iterate through a central spreadsheet that lists all of the specific paths (each spreadsheet contains a tab named "Test" that I am hoping to pull, this tab has the same structure/layout across all spreadsheets) but am having some issues.

I have listed everything that might be helpful below, any insight would be greatly appreciated!

**Existing Code Problems**:

- I receive a TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type class numpy.ndarray specific to the row where I am using concat(df.values) below
- I would like to add a column that lists the "Identifier" value for each spreadsheet in the aggregated dataframe (so that I can group by specific company later on)

**Current Code**:

```
df_0 = pd.read_excel(r'PATH TO CENTRAL SPREADSHEET')
list_of_paths = df_0['Path'].tolist()

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for itr in range(len(list_of_paths)):
    df = pd.read_excel(list_of_paths[itr], sheet_name="Test", ignore_index=True)
    cdf = pd.concat(df.values)
    all_data = all_data.append(cdf,ignore_index=True)
```

**Central Spreadsheet**:

```
Identifier    Path
AAPL          PATH TO UNDERLYING AAPL FILE
GOOG          PATH TO UNDERLYING GOOG FILE
```

**Example of Underlying File ("Test" tab) Structure**

```
Metric   2018    2017
Revenue  2mm     3mm
Expense  1mm     2mm
```

**Desired Output**

```
Metric    Ticker    2018    2017
Revenue   AAPL      2mm     3mm
Revenue   GOOG      5mm     8mm
Expense   AAPL      1mm     2mm
Expense   GOOG      4mm     6mm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing it in steps:

Aim: load the spreadsheets into a list of df's

```
df_0 = pd.read_excel(r'PATH TO CENTRAL SPREADSHEET')
dict_of_paths = {}
for i,j in df_0.iterrows():
     dict_of_paths[j['Identifier']] = j['Path'] 

df_list = []
for key in dict_of_paths.keys():
    df = pd.read_excel(dict_of_paths[key], sheet_name="Test")
    df['ticker'] = key
    df_list.append(df)
```

Now all the df's are in the df_list

```
mdf = pd.concat(df_list,ignore_index=True)
```

As long as the columns are the same. This should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I really appreciate your help! I have been trying (and failing) to get this for days.